# How can I add a new user with SSH access to a Ubuntu VM on Azure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, azure

I feel like this should be an straightforward thing to do, but I'm struggling to find an answer that works...

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running on Azure with the Resource Management type of deployment. It's set up with SSH access so I can log in to it. Now I need to give someone else access to the VM, so I'm trying to add a new SSH key for their user, which I can then revoke at a later date.

What I've tried:

Create a new SSH key on my local machine using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

copied the public key to the VM, to the new user's $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys file

set the authorized_keys file to 600 permissions

restarted the ssh service

tried to log in with

```
ssh newuser@ipaddress
```

And I get a failed attempt with the error

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I'm obviously missing a step somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: The command to add a user is `adduser` or `useradd`.

Comment: The system logs should indicate what the specific problem is. Look at those, then fix it (or ask about fixing it if you don't know how to do it and can't figure it out on your own).

Comment: @qasdfdsaq  I already have the user created, it's getting access via SSH that's the problem.

Comment: Then describe what you did in the question.

Comment: You did not state whether you changed the permission on the `.ssh` directory (in the new user's home folder) to 700.